# Adding new rows to make an Excel spreadsheet complete

Tags: excel

Let's say I have an Excel sheet like the below:

```
      states incidents years
1      Texas         1  2000
2      Texas         1  2008
3    Arizona         2  2004
4 California         1  2002
5 California         4  2007
```

I want to create new rows with the value of 0 for states which had no incidents. For example, I'll create seven new rows for Texas, indicating that it had zero incidents from 2001 to 2007. Arizona will have eight new rows (for all years from 2000 to 2008, except 2004).

How can I do this in Excel? Obviously I can do it manually but I'm wondering if there's a way to automate the process.

Comment: You will need VBA I think

Comment: One would think that you've been around here long enough to realize that *'How can I do this in Excel?'* is an inadequate question for this site.

Comment: You asked [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49433148/1286528) with [r] tag. What's wrong with those answers?  You haven't responded to any of the solutions.

Comment: I intended to find out how to do it in R, but was told to do it in Excel. I have since accepted the solution to the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new table on Sheet2 that fills up with either data from the first table or with zeros.

For the 2-D version: Put the state in the top row and the year on the left row.  Fill the data with an equation like this (starting in cell B2):

```
=iferror(index(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6, match(B$1 & "_" & $A2, Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6 & "_" & Sheet1!$D$2:$D$6, 0)), 0)
```

When you type the formula, accept it by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.  This is an array function.

For the 1-D version, put the state in column A and the year in column B.  Now make column C:

```
=iferror(index(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6, match($A$ & "_" & $B2, Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6 & "_" & Sheet1!$D$2:$D$6, 0)), 0)
```

(Don't forget to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>)

If you format the original data as a Table by using Insert > Table, you will see that the formulas you type get replaced with clever column titles... this will make the entire table's data available to the formula, no matter how much data gets added.  Very useful.